# What's the REST way to verify an email?

Tags: rest, email-validation

When a user register to my web application I send an email to verify his inbox.
In the email there are a link to a resource like this:

```
GET /verify/{token}
```

Since the resource is being updated behind the scenes, doesn't it break the RESTful approach?

How can I do it in a RESTful manner?

Comment: Doesn't add anything behind the scenes? You will give them a form to post to change it? That will be post and update the password, the token just allow them to see the form correctly..

Comment: Behind the scenes I search in the DB what user has this token and set the field to NULL considering valid that user's email.

Comment: Just take to a form (dont touch DB) then post to self and use the get param + the get param and post it to DB and do updates then. If the user hits the URL you dont want to not allow them to hit it again if they need come back to hit surely?

Answer (score 17):

What you are talking about is not REST. REST is for machine to machine communication and not for human to machine communication. You can develop a 1st party REST client, which sends the activation to the REST service.

You can use your verification URI in the browser to access the REST client:

```
# user follows a hyperlink in the browser manually

GET example.com/client/v1/verify/{token}
# asking the client to verify the token
```

and after that the REST client will get the hyperlink for verification from the REST service and send the POST to the service in the background.

```
# the REST client follows the hyperlinks given by the service automatically
# the REST client can run either on the HTTP client or server side

GET example.com/api/v1
# getting the starting page of the REST service
# getting the hyperlink for verification

POST example.com/api/v1/verification {token}
# following the verification hyperlink
```

If you have a server side 1st party REST client, then the HTTP requests to the REST service will run completely on the server and you won't see anything about it in the browser. If you have a client side REST client, then you can send the POST in the browser with AJAX CORS or you can try to POST directly with a HTML form (not recommended). Anyways the activation should be a POST or a PUT.

Comment: I'm agree with you about the activation should be POST or PUT. But in my inexperienced opinion I think that within the REST URI shouldn't be a verb (verify in this case), but on the other hand doens't exist a VERIFY HTTP request.

Comment: @user3482682 Only the URI of the client contains the "verify" verb. The URI of the service contains "verification", which is a noun. Your main problem here that you confuse the browser with a REST client. The browser is not a REST client, it is just a HTTP client.

Comment: Thank you inf3rno for your advices, I marked your answer as useful.

Comment: Well, the web is the best example of a REST though, but mainly the html hypermedia.

Comment: @andho REST is about machine-machine communication not about human-machine, so this is not true.

Comment: I use request library for handle new request inside of my api rest, so in my GET endoint if exists the token i make a request to PUT endpoint for update my user.isActive value, and return the response with success or with fail if it was any error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what are you trying to do.

Does it fire an email after validating the user for example? If so, it is not an idempotent method and you should use POST.

Example:

```
POST /users/{id}/verify/{token}
```

If the method doesn't have any consequence besides the update, I think you should use PUT.

Comment: If the intention is that a user can click a hyperlink in the email received, POST and PUT are not possible unless you start including form-tags; which won't work if the user views the email as plain text.

Comment: Any communication between the REST API and that kind of integration will need a website for the interaction. The hyperlink on the email would need to send the user to an website, not for the API. The website will get a GET /something?token=blabla and send it to the REST API

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you overthinking REST? With e-mail verification you want the user to be able to simply click the link from whatever mail user agent he is using, so you'll end up with a simple GET on the server (presented as a hyperlink to the user) with the token either in the path or as part of the query string:

```
GET http://example.com/verify-email/TOKEN
GET http://example.com/verify-email?token=TOKEN
```

Either is fine for this use case. It is not really a resource you are getting or creating; just a trigger for some process on the backend.

Why do you think this would run afoul of good design?

Comment: I think this would run afol of good design because within the REST URI shouldn't be a verb (verify in this case).

Comment: Confirmation links using GET can cause problems as they might be auto-confirmed by prefetching and so on. See https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=152805

Comment: @Alex is right for clear reason. The article goes back to 2006 already but is still valid.